# python get all keys in subdictorionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, if I have a dictionary with sub dictionaries

```
d = {
    'a' : {
        'aa': {},
        'ab': {},
    },
    'b' : {
        'ba': {},
        'bb': {},
    }
}
```

how I can get the keys of every sub dictionary?

```
d.keys()
d['a'].keys()
d['b'].keys()
```

this is the normal way , but if I have many subdirectories, how I can get the keys of every sub dictionary ?

#### EDIT

I need the keys to access in a dictionary with five or more levels,

```
d[k1][k2][k3][k4][k5]
```

in some case I need the information "under" the k2 key, in other case "under" the k3 key, etc.

Comment: Use recursion. `.keys()` returns a list, so you can keep calling `.keys()` on items of the returned list until it is empty

Comment: Are there only two levels or more?

Comment: @Lawrence the numbers of levels is the real problem, I have more of two levels, (five or fix).

Comment: Oh boy, ask a dictionary-related question and python veterans gather around posting clever algorithms and upvoting each other :D

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just list all the keys? List all unique keys? Do you need to use those keys for something else? You need to be more specific as to what problem you are actually facing.

Comment: But after you accessed the information, do you need to still hold on to the key, or would just finding the dictionary be enough? This is too broad a scenario to answer properly, really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the keys of all levels, you can recurse:

```
def nested_keys(d):
    yield d.keys()
    for value in d.values():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for res in nested_keys(value):
                yield res
```

This is a generator function, you'd loop over the output or call `list` on it. This yields *sequences* of keys, not individual keys. In Python 3, that means you get dictionary views, for example, and empty dictionaries are included:

```
>>> d = {
...     'a' : {
...         'aa': {},
...         'ab': {},
...     },
...     'b' : {
...         'ba': {},
...         'bb': {},
...     }
... }
>>> def nested_keys(d):
...     yield d.keys()
...     for value in d.values():
...         if isinstance(value, dict):
...             for res in nested_keys(value):
...                 yield res
... 
>>> for keys in nested_keys(d):
...     print keys
... 
['a', 'b']
['aa', 'ab']
[]
[]
['ba', 'bb']
[]
[]
```

This isn't all that useful, really, as you don't know what dictionary the keys belonged to.

Comment: Perhaps set up something that will show which key is being processed such as loop over keys k and check d[k] then print before the recursion print 'checking key', k  I was not the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for arbitrary level nested dictionaries

```
d = {
    'a' : {
        'aa': {},
        'ab': {},
    },
    'b' : {
        'ba': {},
        'bb': {},
    }
}

from itertools import chain
def rec(current_dict):
    children = []
    for k in current_dict:
        yield k
        if isinstance(current_dict[k], dict):
            children.append(rec(current_dict[k]))
    for k in chain.from_iterable(children):
        yield k

print list(rec(d))
# ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends if you have dictionaries in the subdictionaries or not. You can create a function that will check the types via recursion

```
def checksubtype(d):
  # d is a dictionary check the subtypes.
  for k in d:
    if type(d[k]) == type(d):
      print 'key', k, 'contains a dictionary'
      checktype(d[k])
    else:
      print 'key', k, 'has type', type(d[k])

>>> d = {'a': {'aa': [1, 2, 3], 'bb': [3, 4]}, 'b': {'ba': [5, 6], 'bb': [7, 8]}}
>>> checksubtype(d)
key a contains a dictionary
key aa has type <type 'list'>
key bb has type <type 'list'>
key b contains a dictionary
key ba has type <type 'list'>
key bb has type <type 'list'>
```

I used a direct check of type rather than isinstance in order to show more obviously what is meant.